# Cypress find() keeping state?

Tags: cypress

I'm using the latest version of Cypress (4.12.0). I'm having problems using two `find()` commands in a row. It seems to me that Cypress is somehow keeping state, which is changed by doing a `find()`.

Here is my Cypress JS code, to find the contents of three fields that are at the same level:

```
1. const shipmentContainer: any = cy.get(`div .shipment-container:contains("${SHIPMENT_LABEL} ${shipmentIndex + 1}")`);
2. shipmentContainer.find('div div').contains(`${TRACKING_NUMBER_LABEL} ${shipment[TRACKING_NUMBER_FIELD]}`);
3. shipmentContainer.find('div div').contains(`${SHIPPING_STATUS_LABEL} ${shipment[SHIPPING_STATUS_FIELD]}`);
4. shipmentContainer.find('div div').contains(`${SHIP_METHOD_LABEL} ${shipment[SHIP_METHOD_FIELD]}`);
```

I'm not including the HTML, because I don't think the details of the data matter.

Here is what is happening. Line 1 sets the container correctly. Line 2 gets the correct data, which I can see in the Cypress UI. But line 3 fails, because it appears to be starting in a totally different location than what the container was set to. If I comment out line 2, then line 3 works, but line 4 doesn't. So only the first `find()`  ever works.

This led me to believe that the container must be keeping state. So I tried the following, but it made no difference at all, which debunked my hyposthesis.

```
const shipmentContainer: any = cy.get(`div .shipment-container:contains("${SHIPMENT_LABEL} ${shipmentIndex + 1}")`);
_.cloneDeep(shipmentContainer).find('div div').contains(`${TRACKING_NUMBER_LABEL} ${shipment[TRACKING_NUMBER_FIELD]}`);
_.cloneDeep(shipmentContainer).find('div div').contains(`${SHIPPING_STATUS_LABEL} ${shipment[SHIPPING_STATUS_FIELD]}`);
_.cloneDeep(shipmentContainer).find('div div').contains(`${SHIP_METHOD_LABEL} ${shipment[SHIP_METHOD_FIELD]}`);
```

Is Cypress itself keeping state on a `find()`? And if so, how can I reset it back so that each of my finds on a container starts in the same location?

Comment: I was able to get this working using Cypress's `within()` function, but I'm still curious why I'm seeing the above behavior.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's because cypress commands are running [asynchronously](https://docs.cypress.io/guides/core-concepts/variables-and-aliases.html#Return-Values):

> **Return Values**

> You cannot assign or work with the return values of any Cypress command. Commands are enqueued and run asynchronously.

For me, I often use [alias](https://docs.cypress.io/api/commands/as.html#Syntax) to reuse the commands:

```
cy.get('div .some-class').as('fancyDiv');
cy.get('@fancyDiv').find('something').contains('bar');
cy.get('@fancyDiv').find('something').contains('foo');
```

Comment: Thanks, @sam-cho , that all makes sense now.